# Change image to black and white when hovering a another element inside it

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been looking for this and I just couldn't find the correct working CSS / jQuery for this.

I'm trying to change my image to black and white when I'm hovering it. So far so good. But once I place content on top of that image and hover it it just goes back to its normal color

```
<div class="uk-float-left uk-width-1-4 project-container">
    <img width="300" height="288" src="project1.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="project1">
    <div class="hidden-content project-content"> 
        <div class="project-button center-absolute"> 
            
        </div>
        <div class="project-name">
            <?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I've tried

```
.project-content:hover > .project-container img {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: url(grayscale.svg); /* Firefox 4+ */
filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */;}
```

I hope you guys can help me out here.

Comment: Proper output HTML would be more useful than PHP. Also, you can't put content **inside** an image only over the top of it. Also your CSS is invalid because you can't select a parent.

Comment: try jquery .... .hover()  ,,,   with parents() .... because i dont think u can do this via css.... its not parent to child .... u talking about child-parent....

Comment: Thank you jaimin moslake. This most certainly pointed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>` selector will only select the immediate child of the element, and in this case there is no `.project-container img` inside `.project-content`.

There is no backwards selection method in CSS at the moment so you will have to either base your transition on `.project-container:hover > img` or use javascript to select the parent on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers i got so far. Made me understand the > css selector a bit better. And @jaimin Moslake gave the answer that pointed me into the right direction. I already thought about it and tryed it but just not in the right way. After jaimin moslake his answer i tryed it again and made a few changes and went with:

```
$(".project-content").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggleClass("gray");
});
```

Im not sure if this is the most correct way to do it but it works.